# Overflow-y: auto not working with mouse wheel, only when sliding the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am using a widget with custom content inside, which is placed in regular `<div>` tags. I have set `max-height` to the content, and I would like to have vertical scrollbar only when needed - that's why I use `overflow-y: auto`.

The scrollbar shows in the right place, but I have an issue scrolling with the mouse wheel. I am able to scroll only by clicking and sliding the scrollbar, but not when I try to scroll with the mouse wheel?

Am I missing to set some other properties? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some code here

Comment: it's a matter of browser and layers, most browsers take in count what you are hovering with your mouse. so if you hover the overflowed area (or one of it's component), the mouse scroll sjould work, if nothing is in the way (even if invisible) for that you can check but right clicking and inspecting the element you are hovering.

Comment: It will be better if you add your code here, so that others can figure out what's the actual problem is.